# I am trying to implement NFA in Python to recognize words but my code doesn't work,

Tags: python, class, nfa

I am trying to implement a method that recognizes words. I have written the following code and have tried to follow my code on paper and execute it step by step with example inputs, but I can't find the reason why my code is not doing what I want him to do. Does anyone see the flaw? I can't see it and I am confused on why it doesn't work.

```
from collections import defaultdict

class NFA:
    def __init__(self, initial, trns, final):
        self.initial = initial
        self.final = set(final)
        self.trns = defaultdict(set)
        for (src, char, tgt) in trns:
            self.trns[src, char].add(tgt)


    def recognizewords(self, strng):
        strang = [char for char in strng]
        strang.reverse()
        visited = set()
        agenda = [self.initial]
        while strang and agenda:
            currentletter = strang.pop()
            current = agenda.pop()
            visited.add(current)
            if (current, currentletter) in self.trns.keys():
                state = self.trns[(current, currentletter)]
                for st in state:
                    if strang == [] and state in self.final:
                        return True
            for i in self.trns[(current, currentletter)]:
                agenda.append(i)
        return False

exampleO = NFA(0, [(0,'o',1), (1,'k',2), (2,'i',1), (2,'!',3)], [3])
print(exampleO.recognizewords("ok!"))
```

It should return True, because at one point my list "strang" will be empty (when I assigned currentletter to "!") and at the same time 3 is in self.final, because self.final is [3] for my object exampleO....

Comment: What you have is more like a DFA. With an NFA, a given character (usually the empty string) can transition from one state to multiple states.

Comment: Oh no I am so sorry I forgot to mention that for now, I restrict my code to only one single character at a time, for simplicity. I really should have mentioned that so my intentions were clear.

Comment: You have a set `visited` that does not seem to be serving any purpose, or am I missing something?

Comment: You have another problem: Consider `NFA(0, [(0,'a',1), (1,'b',2), (1,'b',3), (2,'d',4), (3,'e',4)], [4])`, which should recognize `abd` or `abe`. It fails on `abd` because you are not testing input `d` against the second possible state you can be in after seeing a `b`, namely state 2, because when you get back to the top of the loop, `while strang and agenda:`, `strang` is now empty.

Comment: Yes you are right; i tried to use the visited set for exactly these problems (where he  ignores other possible states) but wasn't able to find a solution yet. You did it with an extra stack I see in your code. I love the idea of using an index rather than looping through a list of characters. Thank you again very much. I just started learning python and after that I really appreciate recursion! haha

Answer (score 0):

This isn't quite a fix to your code because the solution to this type of problem is easier to visualize (at least for me) when you use recursion rather than an explicit stack. And as I mentioned in a comment, an NFA actually allows transitions to multiple states on a given input character including and especially the empty string. So I have modified the input specification to allow a list of new states to be specified for each transition. Here state 0 transitions on the empty string to either state 1 or state 5 (which recognizes `OK`). State 2 can trasition on `k` to either state 3 or 4.

```
from collections import defaultdict

class NFA:
    def __init__(self, initial, trns, final):
        self.initial = initial
        self.final = set(final)
        self.trns = defaultdict(set)
        self.epsilon_states = set()
        for (src, char, tgt) in trns:
            if char == '':
                self.epsilon_states.add(src)
            for state in tgt:
                self.trns[src, char].add(state)

    def recognize_next_char(self, state, strng, index):
        ch = '' if state in self.epsilon_states else strng[index]
        if (state, ch) in self.trns.keys():
            next_states = self.trns[(state, ch)]
            if ch != '':
                index += 1
            for next_state in next_states:
                if index == len(strng):
                    if next_state in self.final:
                        return True
                elif self.recognize_next_char(next_state, strng, index):
                    return True
            return False
        else:
            return False

    def recognizewords(self, strng):
        if len(strng) == 0:
            if self.initial in self.final:
                return True
            if self.initial not in self.epsilon_states:
                return false
        return self.recognize_next_char(self.initial, strng, 0)

exampleO = NFA(0, [(0,'',(1,5)), (1,'o',(2,)), (2,'k',(3,4)), (3,'i',(2,)), (4,'!',(99,)), (5,'O', (6,)), (6,'K',(99,))], [99])
print(exampleO.recognizewords("okikik!"))
print(exampleO.recognizewords("ok!"))
print(exampleO.recognizewords("OK"))
print(exampleO.recognizewords("ok"))
print(exampleO.recognizewords("oki"))
print(exampleO.recognizewords("okx"))
```

Prints:

```
True
True
True
False
False
False
```

**Example of Using Epsilon Transitions to Recognize `ab(cd|ef)gh`**

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for trying to help me. I know recursion is good but I wanted to try it without it for exercise. Another thing I should have mentioned. But you are absolutely right and I am going to study your code closely and hopefully be able to correct my code. Thank you

Comment: Maybe also, if you have time, I am really confused on why my code on the line "  if strang == [] and state in self.final: return True" not returns True. I printed out my "state" and my "strang" and the output confirmed that my code produces the empty list for "strang" and that my state is {3}. I don't understand and it would be so nice if someone could explain this to me aswell. It really makes my head hurt, haha!

Comment: @imboredasf I have to run out now to a wedding and won't be able to look at this again until tomorrow. If somebody hasn't figured it out for you, I will *try* to look at it then. My head hurt, too.

Comment: I figured it out myself and I am ashamed. I used "state" instead of "st" in this conditional and that's why it didn't work. It was literally me using the wrong variable name. .....

Comment: @imboredasf Oh, great! And yours *is* an NFA (I had misspoken) except it does not support transitions on the empty string. Supporting transitions on the empty string is very useful as it is the most straightforward way to recognize regular expressions such as `ab(cd|ef)gh`. I've updated my "answer" to try to illustrate this. Note how state 2 transitions to states 3 and 6 on an empty string and then states 5 and 8 transition to state 9 on an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

So as it turns out that the non-recursive solution is a bit more complicated than what you had to do backtracking correctly (it requires more stacks). I have changed a few variable names, which for me are more logical. There are two versions below. The second one modifeds the first with just a few slight changes to support transitions on empty strings:

```
from collections import defaultdict

class NFA:
    def __init__(self, initial, trns, final):
        self.initial = initial
        self.final = set(final)
        self.trns = defaultdict(set)
        for (src, char, tgt) in trns:
            self.trns[src, char].add(tgt)


    def recognizewords(self, strng):
        strlen = len(strng)
        if strlen == 0:
            return self.initial in self.final
        index = 0
        next_states = [self.initial]
        next_states_stack = []
        index_stack = []
        while index < strlen:
            current_letter = strng[index]
            if next_states:
                state = next_states.pop()
                if (state, current_letter) in self.trns.keys():
                    new_next_states = self.trns[(state, current_letter)]
                    if new_next_states & self.final:
                        # did we use up all the characters?
                        return index == strlen - 1
                    next_states_stack.append(next_states)
                    index_stack.append(index)
                    next_states = list(new_next_states)
                    index += 1
            elif next_states_stack:
                next_states = next_states_stack.pop()
                index = index_stack.pop()
            else:
                return False
        return False

# ab(d|e)
exampleO = NFA(0, [(0,'a',1), (1,'b',2), (1,'b',3), (2,'d',4), (3,'e',4)], [4])
print(exampleO.recognizewords("abd"))
print(exampleO.recognizewords("abe"))
```

Prints:

```
True
True
```

**Variation That Supports Transitions on Empty Strings**

```
from collections import defaultdict

class NFA_Epsilon:
    def __init__(self, initial, trns, final):
        self.initial = initial
        self.final = set(final)
        self.trns = defaultdict(set)
        self.epsilon_states = set()
        for (src, char, tgt) in trns:
            if char == '':
                self.epsilon_states.add(src)
            self.trns[src, char].add(tgt)


    def recognizewords(self, strng):
        strlen = len(strng)
        if strlen == 0:
            return self.initial in self.final
        index = 0
        next_states = [self.initial]
        next_states_stack = []
        index_stack = []
        while index < strlen:
            if next_states:
                state = next_states.pop()
                current_letter = '' if state in self.epsilon_states else strng[index]
                if (state, current_letter) in self.trns.keys():
                    new_next_states = self.trns[(state, current_letter)]
                    if new_next_states & self.final:
                        # did we use up all the characters?
                        return index == strlen - 1
                    next_states_stack.append(next_states)
                    index_stack.append(index)
                    next_states = list(new_next_states)
                    if current_letter != '':
                        index += 1
            elif next_states_stack:
                next_states = next_states_stack.pop()
                index = index_stack.pop()
            else:
                return False
        return False


# ab(cd|ef)gh
example1 = NFA_Epsilon(0, [
    (0,'a',1),
    (1,'b',2),
    (2,'',3),
    (2,'',6),
    (3,'c',4),
    (4,'d',5),
    (5,'',9),
    (6,'e',7),
    (7,'f',8),
    (8,'',9),
    (9,'g',10),
    (10,'h',11)
    ],[11])
print(example1.recognizewords('abcdgh'))
print(example1.recognizewords('abefgh'))
```

Prints:

```
True
True
```